# Automatically apply stereotype of InterfaceBlock to instance in ibd

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way to make a port in a ibd automatically apply the stereotype that is specified in the InterfaceBlock?

Goal is to automatically apply a shapescript to the port when the according Interfaceblock is assigned.

Do i need to write a script?

Using EA14, SysML 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to write a script or an add-in.

Writing a simple script will allow you to set the stereotype when you run the script.

With an add-in (or with a script if you use my open source add-in [EA-Matic](https://bellekens.com/ea-matic/)) you can subscribe to an event (e.g. `EA_OnPostNewElement`) and set the stereotype there automatically without human intervention.

Comment: Thx, i'll have a look at that tool!